# DC-DC Converter Remote ON/OFF logic levels

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I'm trying to interpret the datasheet's description of the positive logic remote ON/OFF pin on this VQE50W-Q24-S5 DC to DC converter. It looks like it's ON when given 3.5 - 75V, or unconnected. Ok, that's pretty easy to understand.

But then it's OFF when... less than 1.2V. This seems to leave quite a bit of information out. If it's ON when unconnected (open) then it must be tied to ground in order to be considered 0 volts right? The datasheet also doesn't seem to define if a negative voltage would turn it off, or the input range. How would you interpret this?

[image]

I was able to find this technical document here from a different manufacturer of power modules and  within that there is this explanation. I wonder if the same applies here?
https://flexpowermodules.com/resources/fpm-designnote021-enabling-with-rc-pin

"For both isolated and non-isolated converters with positive logic, the
converter operates normally if the RC pin is left open or connected
to a high level. The converter is turned off by connecting the
RC pin to a low level or to the negative input. The level definitions
vary from product to product and will be defined later in this
design note. The RC pin is referenced to the negative input."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure where your confusion is?

There's a positive logic input that looks like it's intended to (or at least could be) driven by an open collector, and is pulled up internally. It has to be pulled below 1.2 V to turn the module off.

Then there's a negative logic option that looks like it has an internal pull-down that has to be driven higher than 1.2 V to turn the module off.

Both of those are voltage levels with respect to the - input.

Comment: That was my suspicion as well that there may be a pullup in there. But i'm currently working with a circuit that is supplying the ON pin with an external voltage. I'm assuming this is incorrect usage?

Comment: @BobaJFET I'd think that as long as the circuit you have driving the pin can drive the internal pull-up resistor to the correct voltage levels it should be OK.  But presumably the pull-up could be connected to something as high as 75V, so you'd have to check to see if your circuit is OK with that.  You could just drive a BJT or FET with a 100+ volt rating and be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

If I see "ON when given 3.5 - 75V, or unconnected", I assume that if I leave that pin unconnected, it will be pulled up to a voltage somewhere between 3.5V and 75V by the module. This is an open-collector or open-drain input.

I could likely drive this on/off input with a separately powered 5.0V CMOS logic system, with a '1' turning the output on, and a '0' turning the output off.

I could also drive this with a single transistor that connects this pin to ground, driving the input as the open-drain/open-collector input that it is.

The negative logic option is basically the same electrical input, just the logic operation is flipped.

There's a bunch of ways to implement this circuit, depending on what actually is on the other side of the pin. Guessing how things are connected is a bit tricky, but given that this is an input-referred voltage, the switching regulator is on the primary side. The regulator IC might have a 5V internal regulator for some simple logic and control voltages, so this is how it might be implemented:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXmXDr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Are you saying that it can either be supplied 3.5 - 75V externally, otherwise it will pull-up to that on it's own? What might the internal circuit look like to handle that?

Comment: Correct - it's probably pulled up to the positive power input. I gave an example input circuit, but there's probably more details that could be added and more situations that might need protection (e.g. to protect against a strong driver of ON/OFF). It could also be a much simpler analog circuit as well - not really worth figuring it out 100% as the intended way is just with an open-collector/open-drain setup